# How do I disable telemetry for all users in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sccm

I need to disable telemetry for Visual Studio code for all users. I have packaged the product in SCCM (specifically so its installed under the users profile so they can update it themselves).

I can't however figure out how to disable telemetry for all users.

I know individually the following needs to be added under the user's settings

```
{
"telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
"telemetry.enableTelemetry": false
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the visual studio side of the thing but with sccm you could theoretically deploy the individual settings for every user that logs into the computer. Would not really recommend it because such things are always a little wonky in case you ever have to debug but if noone knows a solution that just allows global settings with vs code I could write you an answer explaining that part.

Answer (score 15):

Telemetry and data collection cannot be disabled in VSCode and the provided options to disable it is a **red herring**, see [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/80d8wu/just_realised_that_visual_studio_code_sends/duvaf76/) for details. Essentially this is the same situation as with Windows 10 because, well, Microsoft.

As an alternative, you can use [VSCodium](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium) but bear in mind 2 things:

1. Some extensions won't work.
2. Even if you hack them into work - they won't work properly or reliably (C# extension, for example, crashes, produces wrong results, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

Since VSC is OpenSource, somebody took already care of that and provides a fork without telemetry:
            https://vscodium.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is now a "How to disable telemetry reporting" section in official VS Code docs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_how-to-disable-telemetry-reporting

> If you don't want to send usage data to Microsoft, you can set the telemetry.telemetryLevel user setting to off.

> From File > Preferences > Settings, search for telemetry, and set the Telemetry: Telemetry Level setting to off. This will silence all telemetry events from VS Code going forward.

> Important Notice: VS Code gives you the option to install Microsoft and third party extensions. These extensions may be collecting their own usage data and are not controlled by the telemetry.telemetryLevel setting. Consult the specific extension's documentation to learn about its telemetry reporting.